# Reformatting SubjectDN Data Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of python code set up that retrieves the subjectDN from a list of certificates based on some search criteria.  All information for each certificate is done on a line by line basis.  The format is as follows:

C="ISO code", ST="province", L="locality", O="org name", OU="org unit", CN="name of certificate"

An example of one of my files would be:

C=US, ST=California, L=Oakland, O=Acme Ltd., OU=Web Services, CN=www.acme.com

C=US, ST=California, L=Oakland, O=Acme Ltd., OU=Web Services, CN=portal.acme.com

C=US, ST=California, L=Oakland, O=Acme Ltd., OU=Web Services, CN=sardine.acme.com

I would like to transform this into a working CSV file which normally would seem pretty easy but some of these rows contain additional data:

businessCategory=Private Organization, juridictionCountry=US, C=US, ST=California, L=Oakland, O=Acme Ltd., OU=Web Services, CN=www.acme.com

This additional data throws all of the columns out of line.

I want to do two things with this data.

1. I want to have only the fields from the first example show up in the CSV file for each column; so C, ST, L, O, OU and CN (omitting the weird fields found in various certificates).
2. I want to omit the "C=" or "ST=" from each value.

I have tried using the CSV module but I can only get this data formatted exactly the same as it is now.  I have also tried using the re module within python to rewrite some of the lines but I'm very confused on the expressions with re.

The idea that I had was to read each line in the output file that I have and then include a for loop for each line to seek out the fields I need and rewrite them.  Something like:

```
def rewrite()
    common_name = #here is where I would do a re command
    if #CN= x, is found (where x is the data I want):
        ofile.write("www.acme.com")
    organization = #here is where I would do a re command
    if #O= x, is found (where x is the data I want):
        ofile.write("Acme Ltd.")
--snip--
    ofile.write("\n")
```

Essentially I would run this function for each line in the input file to an output file.  Something like:

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        rewrite()
```

Is this a good way to do this or is there an easier way?  Can someone help me with the regular expression to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can be sure about the **order**  of the entries, you could extract the data with a regular expression and form a pandas dataframe out of it afterwards:

```
import re, pandas as pd

string = """
C=US, ST=California, L=Oakland, O=Acme Ltd., OU=Web Services, CN=www.acme.com

C=US, ST=California, L=Oakland, O=Acme Ltd., OU=Web Services, CN=portal.acme.com

C=US, ST=California, L=Oakland, O=Acme Ltd., OU=Web Services, CN=sardine.acme.com

businessCategory=Private Organization, juridictionCountry=US, C=US, ST=California, L=Oakland, O=Acme Ltd., OU=Web Services, CN=www.acme.com
"""

rx = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{1,2}=([^\n\r,]+)')

data = [(rx.findall(line)) for line in string.split("\n") if line]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns = ['CountryName', 'StateOrProvinceName', 'Locality', 'Organization', 'OrganizationalUnit', 'CommonName'])
print(df)
```

... which would yield:

```
  CountryName StateOrProvinceName Locality Organization OrganizationalUnit  \
0          US          California  Oakland    Acme Ltd.       Web Services   
1          US          California  Oakland    Acme Ltd.       Web Services   
2          US          California  Oakland    Acme Ltd.       Web Services   
3          US          California  Oakland    Acme Ltd.       Web Services   

         CommonName  
0      www.acme.com  
1   portal.acme.com  
2  sardine.acme.com  
3      www.acme.com
```

Comment: I've tried it but if fails due to the weird entries. Every now and then there is a line that has all the values I want but also some extras.  When I attempt your code, I get the following: AssertionError: 6 columns passed, passed data had 8 columns.  Is there a way to seek out and remove these entries before I attempt your suggestion?  Like a way to remove "CN=some_text," completely (only it wouldn't be for CN=, it would be for "businessCategory=some_text" and similar fields.

Comment: I did some messing around and I'm almost there.  Here is what I did: `result = open("string.txt", "r")`
`file_read = result.read()`
`rm = re.sub(r'[\w]{6,19}=([^.\,]+)', "", file_read)`
The only problem with my sub is that is still includes the comma, so the record looks like ,,,C=data, L=data ...and so forth.